# How to get days between interactions and conversations and being able to filter that in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to know if seeing the following is possible:

1. ROAS of new users vs. returning users
2. How many days until conversion after the first interaction
3. How many interactions did the customer have before they made the donation
4. How many days were before the first interaction and donation
5. How many days were between the first and second donation
6. How many donations were made by a person ( average)? And the best 20% are how many?
7. Customer paths to conversion with sources start with a specific campaign.

I've tried playing around in the attribution tab with the models and conversation paths but to no avail

Comment: I suggest you explain what you have already tried to do, rather than asking if something is possible or not.

Comment: updated my post